# How can you make a .xib file fill the whole screen width (Swift)

Tags: swift, uiview, uiscrollview, constraints, xib

I want a UIScrollView which contains to other views. One is a UITableView and the other is a MKMapView. To do this I created two xib files. When I want to add these two to my scroll view I do it like this:

```
 func setupScrollView() {
    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width * 2, height: self.view.bounds.height)
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.delegate = self
}

func loadScrollViewViews() {

    if let tableView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ViewTableShow", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? ViewTableShow {
        scrollView.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.frame.size.width = self.view.bounds.size.width
        tableView.frame.origin.x = 0
    }

    if let mapView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ViewMapShow", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? ViewMapShow {
        scrollView.addSubview(mapView)
        mapView.frame.size.width = self.view.bounds.size.width
        mapView.frame.origin.x = self.view.bounds.width
    }
}
```

First I call `setupScrollView` and then `loadScrollViewViews` in the `viewDidLoad` function in my ViewController class. `self.view.bounds.size.width` gives me the correct size of the screen width but it doesn't seems to set the width for the two views properly.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBFgV.gif) is what it looks like right know. I want to cover the whole screen width. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Looks like scrollView.frame.size.width is wrong. Where do you set the frame of scrollView?

Comment: I don't think so, otherwise the starting position of each view would also be wrong but that's not the problem.

Comment: Where and how did you set the frame of scrollView? Also can you check frame?

Comment: Thank you so much! I was sitting here for hours for figuring out that I didn't set the frames width with `scrollView.frame.size.width = self.view.bounds.width`. It works now!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some constraints to your scrollView

Comment: I added some constraints to my scrollView in the storyboard. And I think it's not a problem of the scrollView rather than the xib files which don't adjust the right way.